# Rails Admin -> only access if user have role admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello I just discovered the gem railsadmin, I configured it but currently all users have access to the administration part by typing admin in their url, I would like to limit access and allow it only to users with the admin role.

In my user table, I already have a role column and I write "admin" to make a user -> super user

```rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
 ## == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
end
```

Actually all users have access to the administration dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using devise, you can restrict access via `routes.rb`

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.role == "admin" } do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
end
```

Or you can use an authorization gems like `cancancan` [(how to use)](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancancan)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Rails 6:

```rb
authenticate :user, (->(user) { user.admin? }) do
    mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
end
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.